# How can i add generated AES key from Diffie-Hellman class to the class where i use the key

Tags: java, encryption, aes, diffie-hellman

Background: I have two devices which communicate via IP/port connection establishing live voice encrypting communication thanks to Diffie-Hellman key-exchange and encrypting it thanks to AES algorithm.  Now some of the code is written and some just taken to use as an example of the prototype implementation.

Problem: Now even when understanding how my classes work just like the title states: ***I can not figure out how to take the key from DH class and declare in AES class that this is the key it must use to encrypt.***

P.s. Advice on code optimization, better practices and general tips are most welcome, please. 
Thank you for your time.

public class DH extends Thread {

```
int bitLength=512;  
int certainty=20;//

private static final SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

public DH() throws Exception{
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    BigInteger generatorValue,primeValue,publicA,publicB,secretA,secretB,sharedKeyA,sharedKeyB;

    primeValue = findPrime();// BigInteger.valueOf((long)g);
    System.out.println("the prime is "+primeValue);
     generatorValue = findPrimeRoot(primeValue);//BigInteger.valueOf((long)p);
    System.out.println("the generator of the prime is "+generatorValue);

    // on machine 1
    secretA = new BigInteger(bitLength-2,randomGenerator);
    // on machine 2
    secretB = new BigInteger(bitLength-2,randomGenerator);

    // to be published:
    publicA=generatorValue.modPow(secretA, primeValue);
    publicB=generatorValue.modPow(secretB, primeValue);
    sharedKeyA = publicB.modPow(secretA,primeValue);// should always be same as:
    sharedKeyB = publicA.modPow(secretB,primeValue);

    String getAValue=sharedKeyA.toString();

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    md.update(getAValue.getBytes());

    byte byteData[] = md.digest();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i=0;i<byteData.length;i++)
    {
        sb.append(Integer.toString((byteData[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));// ??
    }

    String getHexValue = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("hex format in SHA-256 is "+getHexValue);

    byte [] initkey = getAValue.getBytes("UTF-8");

    MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    initkey =  sha.digest(initkey);
    initkey = Arrays.copyOf(initkey, 16);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec =  new SecretKeySpec(initkey,"AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);



}
```

As you can see i have coded AES key and IV statically but want for the generated AES key in DH to be assigned in this class

public class AES {

```
static String IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
static String initkey = "13B_0(wcXNGkHAR[";

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plainData, int offset, int length) throws Exception {


    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");//CBC
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(initkey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return cipher.doFinal(plainData, offset, length);
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherSound, int offset, int length) throws Exception {

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");//CBC
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(initkey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    return cipher.doFinal(cipherSound, offset, length);
}
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately there are plenty of things to be fixed :(  Your DH is not complete, search a little, e. g. see [other sites](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/DiffieHellmanKeyAgreement.htm), missing some security checks (for weak parameters), the way you use the cipher object is not suitable for streams, dubious use of encoded data,...

Answer (score 0):

> figure out how to take the key from DH class and declare in AES class that this is the key it must use to encrypt

Please check this [tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/DiffieHellmanKeyAgreement.htm)

Then you can use the returned secret:

```
byte[] masterKey = aKeyAgree.generateSecret();
// maybe hash the master key too
SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(masterKey, 0, 16, "AES");
```

However, if you have two way communication, you either need random IV or different keys for each direction (derived from the master)

Additional hint :

> I have two devices which communicate via IP/port connection establishing live voice encrypting communication

Maybe your devices are powerful enough to establish proper TLS, what would solve many things for you

Comment: I will check it out and let you know how it helped. It is a two-way communication although i am having trouble making one of the two devices working to send packets over.  TLS is not possible as it is not a business solution or hobby, but an academic subject which i am quite frankly very new to and it has been decided to implement DH + AES way.